# Background on body element

Tags: html, css

How can i put background on body in css , but i dont want the header and nav menu to be on same background too. I want the  background color be under the header ( my header is arounded with the color too).

Comment: You can do that with CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this result, you want to give the header and nav a different color than the body. 
 Here is an example:

```
header {background-color:red;} 
nav {background-color:yellow;}
body {background-color:black;}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can do this:

```css
header{
   background-color:<color_1>
}
body{
   background-color:<color_2>
}
nav{
   background-color:<color_3>
}
```

you should change  by color you want